# Tableau, Gantt Chart: Duration (minutes) not lining up with the x-axis (Start Time, HH:MM)

Tags: tableau-api, gantt-chart

I have a Gantt chart in Tableau where I am looking at a Start Time in form of HH:MM and an End Time usually 5-40min later (so not days).

My x-axis is showing the Start Time and I have tried both: putting in the duration into size as integer as well as datepart.

Total_Parking_Time = Integer | Calc Duration = DATEDIFF('minute',[Arrival Time],[Dept Time])

The result is the same, the axis shows something like a tick at 8:06 and at 8:19. While the duration of the first bar starting at 8:06 is 39min, it does not reach the 8:19 tick mark on the axis.

Thanks a lot.

[Tableau Gantt Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaKum.png)